# Replace all Occurences of "Key" within commas in python

Tags: python

I have a dump from a mariadb i need to edit. The dump contains key statements i want to filter out.

Is there a way to edit a String that cuts out all substrings that follow the pattern ,*"Key"*,?

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
Primary Key(`PersonID`),
Foreign Key(`City`)
);
```

Desired Output:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

i want to iterate over a file containing multiple statements of that sort in python.

Comment: I think you can do this in even in Notepad++. When you have a pattern in mind - this is regex. This is the most simple and naïve pattern "^.*?\sKey\(.*?\),?$"

Comment: are the commas also part of this pattern?

Comment: Yes, look at the example. There is primary key with trailing comma and foreign without. So the ".?" - question mark means 0 or 1 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we're not ChatGPT - please try to come up with something on your own before posting to SO.
I'm going to make an exception this time.

We can use the python's 're' module (for regular expressions) to remove substrings that follow the pattern 'Key'.

```
import re

# your input
input_string = """
CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
Primary Key(`PersonID`),
Foreign Key(`City`)
);
"""

# pattern to look for 
pattern = r".*Key\([^)]*\)\s*,|.*Key\([^)]*\)\s*"

# remove all substrings that match the pattern
output_string = re.sub(pattern, "", input_string)

# print output
print(output_string)
```

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

To find out what regular expression you need, you can use this site [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to test until you get your needed expression.

Comment: Sorry pretty new to this site. If i run your code, it provides the following output: 
CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
Primary Key(`PersonIDCity`)
);

so the primary key is still there

Comment: You're completely right, I'm sorry. Missed something in the pattern. Try again please.

Comment: it works now, the only problem is i still have the trailing comma after city:
CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),

);

Answer (score 1):

Like Michael has already said, we are not ChatGPT.

A similar solution which does not use regex, would be as follows

```
data = """CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
Primary Key(`PersonID`),
Foreign Key(`City`)
);"""

#split into individual lines
dataArr = data.split("\n")

#function which returns whether string (x) contains 'Key' or not
def containsKey(x):
    return ("Key" not in x)

#returns new array with elements containing 'Key' removed
dataArr = filter(containsKey,dataArr)

#joins lines into single string
data = "\n".join(dataArr)
print(data)
```

outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
);
```